# efficient extraction of elements from a C++ unordered set

Tags: c++, set, unordered-set

In C++ suppose you have an unordered set (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) of strings - is there a way to efficiently extract all strings from that set that meet a certain criteria (e.g. find all strings in the set that begin with letter "a") using a method other than iterating through the entire set with a for loop and checking the first character of every single string?

Comment: Technically, no. Of course you can use some algorithms or functions but they will iterate over the container in a loop. You can use a while loop instead of a for loop ;-)

Comment: If you need to check every element, there's no way to do it without iterating over the set one way or another. You could use [standard algorithm functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to do it, which hides the iteration from you and are highly optimized, but they still have to iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *any criteria* this is not possible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62448739/2261538) for some more details.

Depending on your other needs, a **sorted** `std::vector` is *highly likely* to be the most efficient for the extraction part alone. Use algorithms like [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to work with a **sorted** `std::vector`. In the end, your actual use cases is what determines overall which container is best suited performance-wise - although `std::vector` comes close to a one-size fit all for considering performance (this is because of all *the internal* optimizations of contiguous storage).

That being said, in general it's advisable to use the container that seems best suited for the problem at hand and only do clever optimizations if there's an actual performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

For the general case of *any criteria*, you can't do better than iterating over every element.

Each container has *specific criteria* that it can do better with, e.g.

```
std::set<std::string> strings = /* something */;
auto first = strings.lower_bound("a"); // O(log(strings)), "a" is the least string that starts with 'a'
auto last = strings.lower_bound("b"); // O(log(strings)), "b" is the first string after those that start with 'a'
strings.erase(first, last); // O(log(strings) + distance(first, last)), all the strings starting with 'a' are removed
```

Here we remove elements starting with `'a'`, with a complexity of `O(log(strings) + distance(first, last))` which is a `O(alphabet)` improvement over iterating all elements.

Or the more contrived

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> strings = /* something */;
auto hashed = strings.hash_function()("Any collision will do"); // O(1)
strings.erase(strings.begin(hashed), strings.end(hashed)); // O(distance(first, last))
```

Here we remove elements that hash the same as `"Any collision will do"`, with a complexity of `O(distance(first, last))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an unordered set, adapt your data structure to something like a trie.
In this case it might be more useful to you.

For more details please check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/.

Depending on your needs you might think of some other algorithms like Aho-Corasick/Suffix-Arrays etc. You might need to do some research on the data-structure you need based on the amount of data that you have, the recomputing that you need and the amount of queries that you do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Edited, I meant ```std::unordered_set```, but it is the same as for ```std::set```.

Comment: What I meant is that, don't think about rather extending your data structure that you first feel appropriate, which might lead to really bad complexity results, but rather have a look at several data-structures and based on your needs use the best you need.